# change multiple css elements of one div on jquery scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm new to jquery and trying to learn as much as i can on my own, but I am stuck here. I am trying to get a container that is in a fixed position to adjust opacity and change font color on scroll. I have gotten the opacity part down using the code below. how do i combine other css changes to this like changing the color of the font from `#000000` to `#ffffff`

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
  function EasyPeasyParallax() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    var targetOpacity = 1;
    scrollPos < 400 ? targetOpacity = '0.' + (scrollPos * 100) / 10 : targetOpacity;
    $('.headcon').css({
      'background-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + targetOpacity + ')'
    });
    console.log(scrollPos, targetOpacity);
  };
  $(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      EasyPeasyParallax();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your opacity code isn't correct. You shouldn't have an assignment in the second part of the ternary operator.  To answer your original question, simply append more property settings to the object passed to the `css` function.

```
jQuery(function  ($) {

    function EasyPeasyParallax() {
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        // use the result of ternary operator to assign the opacity by
        // rather than assigning in the second operator
        var targetOpacity = scrollPos < 400 
                               ? (scrollPos*100)/10 
                               : 1;
        $('.headcon').css({
            'background-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, '+ targetOpacity +')',
            'font-color': '#ffffff'
          });

      console.log(scrollPos,targetOpacity);
    };

    $(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            EasyPeasyParallax();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help there :) one last question if you dont mind. when i scroll back up to top font is staying black. how would i get it to return to its original color of white?

Comment: @robgfl23 off the top of my head I would say that you want to scale the color as well so that it darkens/lightens with scroll.  alternatively you could just flip it between black/white once the scroll position reaches a certain point.  `var fontColor = scrollPos < 400 ? '#ffffff' : '#000000';` and then use `fontColor` in the `css` function.